# Wondering about a line in Hoshanot for Shabbat

Tags: shabbat, words, sukkot

The special Hoshanot for Shabbat mostly contain praises for B'nei Yisrael related to Shabbat. However, i don't get the י line:

> יושבת וממתנת עד כלות שבת
>
> She sits and waits until the end of Shabbat.

Who does this refer to, and how is it a praise?